# How i can change button marginEnd with LiveData and BindingAdapter?

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, android-databinding

How i can change button marginEnd with LiveData and BindingAdapter?
My LiveData in ViewModel:
`var marginRight = MutableLiveData(R.dimen.default_margin)`

My dimen
`<dimen name="default_margin">141dp</dimen>`

and my attribute: `android:layout_marginEnd="@{viewmodel.marginRight}"`

In this case i get

```
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.Button android:layout_marginEnd> that accepts parameter type 'androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.lang.Integer>'
If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching the Internet, I realized that there is no setter for the margin. It helped me:

LiveData:

```
var marginRight = MutableLiveData(R.dimen.margin_right_default)
```

My BindingAdapter:

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("app:marginRight")
    fun setMarginRight(view: View, marginResource: Int){
        val resources = view.context.resources
        val params = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.setMargins(0,0, resources.getDimension(marginResource).toInt(), 0)
        view.layoutParams = params
    }
```

and my attribute:

```
app:marginRight="@{viewmodel.marginRight}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have dimen id instead of dimen value in your MutableLiveData, but i think you can't do that in xml because views does not have setters for margins. You can do it in code with MarginLayoutParams.